# com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID permission is not added automatically

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

On the [release notes page](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#analytics_v20-1-1) of Firebase Android SDK, it mentions that the permission will be added to the manifest automatically. I didn't do anything to remove that permission but it's not on the merged manifest. And when I upload the bundle to the store, I get the infamous *Your advertising ID declaration* error on the console. I'm using firebase-bom version 32.5.0 meaning that analytics is 21.5.0. What am I missing here? Is this a bug?